# Chrome Extension - Check for active subscription

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-api

We are offering a chrome extension that is subscription-based and uses the built-in Google Chromestore payments.

While google provides some extensive documentation on how to verify if a user obtained a licence via one-time payment [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment), there is no information on how to verify that the subscription has not been cancelled by the customer in their google [payments](https://payments.google.com/payments/u/0/home#subscriptionsAndServices) subscriptions section.

Does anyone know how to check this?

Comment: Isn't it that the [`getPurchases`](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#get-purchases) API was made for this use-case? Where you could check for the `state` if it's `CANCELLED`.

Comment: I am currently checking this, will know more in 30 days. The problem is that recurring payments for chrome extensions produce an order and a service subscription, both ca be cancelled separately by the user. what i know for a fact is: cancelling the subscription does not set the state to CANCELLED (at least not right away, maybe within the next invoice cycle), cancelling the order sets the state to cancelled, but also removes the extension.

Comment: BEWARE chrome store programmers: the chrome store payments are absoluty terrible with zero support from google. most payments will fail. look for another provider like stripe, which also wont require chrome sign-in.

Comment: I'm looking for the solution, @jvataman please share if you got to find anything. Thank you!